# R regex using a vector and two column dataframe

Tags: regex, r

Suppose I have a vector and a two column data.frame.

```
motif <- c("DAGTACTHV","AGT","WSAT")

motif_ref <- data.frame("sym"=c("W","S","M","K","R","Y","B","D","H","V","N"),
                              "bases"=c("(A|T)","(C|G)","(A|C)","(G|T)","(A|G)","(C|T)","(C|G|T)","(A|G|T)","(A|C|T)","(A|C|G)","(A|C|G|T)"))
```

I'm trying to use `stri_replace_all` to replace all elements in `motif_ref$sym` with the corresponding elements in `motif_ref$bases`, in `motif`.

```
m <- stri_replace_all_regex(motif, motif_ref$sym, motif_ref$bases)
```

However this gives me:

```
> m
[1] "DAGTACTHV"       "DAGTACTHV"       "DAGTACTHV"       "DAGTACTHV"       "DAGTACTHV"       "DAGTACTHV"       "DAGTACTHV"      
 [8] "(A|G|T)AGTACTHV" "DAGTACT(A|C|T)V" "DAGTACTH(A|C|G)" "DAGTACTHV"
```

when I actually want something like:

```
> m 
[1] "(A|G|T)AGTACT(A|C|T)(A|C|G)" "AGT" "(A|T)(C|G)AT"
```

I was thinking about using `chartr`, however I dont know if it'll work on replacing single characters with longer strings.

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for its `vectorize_all` argument.

```
library(stringi)

stri_replace_all_fixed(motif, motif_ref$sym, motif_ref$bases, vectorize_all = FALSE)
# [1] "(A|G|T)AGTACT(A|C|T)(A|C|G)" "AGT"                         "(A|T)(C|G)AT"
```

Or a bit more clearly written -

```
with(motif_ref, {
    stri_replace_all_fixed(motif, sym, bases, vectorize_all = FALSE)
})
```

**Note** that using `stri_replace_all_fixed` will be more efficient since we are searching for exact matches.